# Can I only have a clock process?

Tags: heroku, apscheduler

I am building a Python application with APScheduler that fires one job every hour for a certain time period during the day. It is NOT a web application. The job is guaranteed to finish in 60 minutes. Currently, I only use a clock process. My Procfile looks like:

```
clock: python app.py
```

I came across this documentation https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes#overview which advices me to "Use a job scheduler only to queue background jobs, not to execute them".

I think my current approach is not following the suggestion on this article. In my approach, the clock process schedules AND executes the job. However, I am not running a "background job". The scheduled job is the ONLY job the app fires/runs. And my app has worked correctly so far. My question is, in my case, are there any disadvantages to my approach?

Thank you!